# select count change value from another table

Tags: php, mysql

i want to ask

i have 2 table :

1. table product (no, product_name, price, city)
2. table city (no_city, city_name)

in table product field "city" show data "no_city"

i mean like this in table product :

```
no | product_name | price | city
1  | apple        | $5    | 1
```

and in table city like this :

```
no_city | city_name
1       | london
```

i have a code for chartjs

i use count data from database, this my code

```
$city = $GLOBALS['conn']->GetAll("SELECT city AS `labels`, COUNT(city) AS `values` FROM product GROUP BY city");
```

in chart preview data city show "1" it should be the city "london"

the problem is how to change number "1" in chart preview to city name "london"

i try to use INNER JOIN but not effectiv

please help me sir

how to change number "1" in chart preview to city name "london"

thank you

Comment: You need to read up on sql aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Use an join to bring in the city names from the other table:

```
SELECT
    c.city_name AS labels,
    COUNT(p.city) AS values
FROM city c
LEFT JOIN product p
    ON p.city = c.no_city
GROUP BY
    c.no_city, c.city_name
```

Note that it makes logical sense to left join the `city` to `product` table, because that guarantees that every city would appear in your result set.  For those cities having no products, a count of zero would be reported.

Comment: thank you sir for you reply, can i ask? what "p" and "c" in city c and product p?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LEFT JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) to handle the cases where there are cities with no products.

try this code :

```
$city = $GLOBALS['conn']->GetAll(
  "SELECT
     city.city_name AS `labels`,
     COUNT(product.city) AS `values`,
     city.no_city
   FROM city c
   LEFT JOIN product p
     ON p.city = c.no_city
   GROUP BY c.no_city"
);
```

Comment: can i ask sir? 
INNER JOIN city c
city c << c is?